# @PreAuthorize annotation resolve last variable with wrong way

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, security, annotations

I'm using @PreAuthorize annotation of 'org.springframework.security.access.prepost'.

Please see my dev environment.

```
- language: kotlin
- framework: SpringBoot 2.5.0
- implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
- implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
```

When I try to access the variable ***a*** such as following way, it works good.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#a, 'Document', T(io.myproject.Permission).WRITE)")
suspend fun deleteProject(@PathVariable a: String, @PathVariable b: String) {
// something
}
```

But when I try to access the variable that last of the function, it has gone wrong way.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#a, 'Document', T(io.myproject.Permission).WRITE)")
suspend fun deleteProject(@PathVariable b: String, @PathVariable a: String) {
// something
}
```

The last variable contains the value and function('body' of deleteProject).
So variable type is ***object array***.

```
a = {Object[2]@10801}
       {String} "TheValue"
       {KCallables$callSuspend$1@12659} "Continuation at kotlin.reflect.full.KCallables.callSuspend(KCallables.kt:55)"
```

I checked it in SecurityExpressionRoot.java.

```
@Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Object targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {
        return this.permissionEvaluator.hasPermission(this.authentication, (Serializable) targetId, targetType,
                permission);
    }
```

As you know the targetId of the function is the variable ***a***.

Is it bug of Spring security?

Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issues.

org/springframework/context/expression/MethodBasedEvaluationContext.java line 71
lazyLoadArguments will attach KCallables$callSuspend to last element.
My temp solution is do type check....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30636497)

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work using custom parameter names:

```kotlin
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#z, 'Document', T(io.myproject.Permission).WRITE)")
suspend fun deleteProject(@PathVariable b: String, @Param("z") @PathVariable a: String) {
    // something
}
```